# How to move a PictureBlock build dynamically

Tags: c#, list, forms

I haven't found a similar question but  maybe I haven't found the good keys word, my apologies if there is one.
It's my first question on this website so please tell me if I should ask my question differently! :)

I'm trying to create some pictureblock in a panel thanks to a button and drag and drop them but I don't know how to call the pictureBlock by clicking on it

I tried this, I'm able to create the block by clicking on a button and I'm able the move the last block created but I can't move other blocks.
I tried many solutions but I don't understand how to call the pictureblock i clicked on instead of calling "structures[i]"

Thank you for your help!

form 1 :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ajout_panel1();
        ajout_panelI();
    }
    private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox_MouseDown(this.structures[i], e);
        pictureBox_MouseMove(this.structures[i], e);
    }

    private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        { 
                this.structures[i-1].Left = e.X + this.structures[i-1].Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                this.structures[i-1].Top = e.Y + this.structures[i-1].Top - MouseDownLocation.Y; }
        }
    }
```

Form 1 designer:

```
  private void ajout_panelI()
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox newbox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.structures.Add(newbox);

        panel1.SuspendLayout();
        SuspendLayout();
        panel1.Controls.Add(this.structures[i]);
        this.structures[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.GradientActiveCaption;
        this.structures[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(pos_x, pos_y);
        this.structures[i].Name = pic_name();
        this.structures[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
        this.structures[i].TabIndex = 0;
        this.structures[i].MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox_MouseDown);
        this.structures[i].MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox_MouseMove);
        this.structures[i].Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel2_Paint_1);
        panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        ResumeLayout(false);

        
        pos_y = pos_y + 150;
        i++;


    }
    public System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox panel2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    public int i = 0;
    private int pos_x =30;
    private int pos_y =30;

    private List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox> structures { get; set; } = new List<System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox>();
   
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox structure;
    
    private string name;
```

Comment: All pboxes should have the same handlers. There the sender can be cast to pBox (`var Pbox = sender as PictureBox;`) and then the relvant code can refer to that variable. As to which box you really want to act on I don't quite follow your code. - As it is your code always refers to the same one as you use a public index called `i`; bad name, bad concept. You can have a pulic varible `PictureBox currentBox` which you could set in the mouse down event.

Comment: Hello and welcome. "this.structures[i-1]"  --> this code is always moving the same object. Try to map the pictureblocks and then access it. use "sender" to distinguish which pictureblock to move.

Comment: I casted the sender to `pBox` as you said and it worked! 
I'll delete the `i` out of my code as well.
thank you for your answer and your advice as well!